# Programmatically adding an email to a Stripe Charge

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments, payment-processing

I have the following piece of code handling POSTs from the form:

```
app.post('/:advertorial/payment', async (req, res) => {
  const advertorial = req.params.advertorial
  const stripeToken = req.body.stripeToken

  stripe.charges.create({
    amount: COSTS.RESTBETTER_DILATOR_PRICE,
    currency: 'usd',
    description: `Example charge for ${new Date()}`,
    source: stripeToken,
    receipt_email: req.body.result.token.email,
    metadata: {
      'customer_email': req.body.result.token.email
    }
  }).then(
    function (result) { res.send(JSON.stringify(result)) },
    function (err) { res.json(err) }
  )
})
```

Interestingly, metadata is saved fine. According to the [documentation, `receipt_email` should be a field that I can include but in the resulting charge item in Stripe it is nowhere to be found](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object)

On the other hand, the metadata piece seems to work:

[image]

What am I missing here?